# Different variadic template expansion

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, c++14

I want to prepare list of pairs of values from structure using variadic templates.

```
#include <vector>

struct foo
{
    foo(int a, int b)
        : a(a), b(b) {}
    int a;
    int b;
};

struct Msg
{
    std::vector<int> valueArray;    
};

template<typename... Args>
Msg func(Args... args)
{
    Msg msg;
    msg.valueArray = { sizeof...(args), (args.a)..., (args.b)... };
    return msg;
}

int main() {
    Msg msg = func(foo{1,2}, foo{3,4}, foo{5,6});
}
```

Msg which func will return will have `valueArray = [3, 1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6]`.

Is there any simple way to expand variadic paremeters in a way, where valueArray will look like `valueArray = [3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`?

Comment: You can't assign to arrays.

Comment: I changed to vector, but this not revelant to this question ;)

Comment: Considering your question does not use compile-time values, would a call to `std::sort` after assigning the scrambled values not do?

Comment: @chris I used 1,2,3,4,5,6 values to easy point out which order in array i expect to receive. In my application, foo values have not any order, and they are compile time known.

Comment: Oh, I see what you're getting at now. Sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following is not as generic as I'd like to, but maybe it is sufficient for you:

```
template<typename Arr, std::size_t... Is>
Msg func2( const Arr& arr, std::index_sequence<Is...> )
{
    Msg msg;
    msg.valueArray = {
        sizeof...(Is) / 2,
        ( ( Is % 2 == 0 ) ? std::get< Is / 2 >( arr ).a
                          : std::get< Is / 2 >( arr ).b )... };
    return msg;
}

template<typename... Args>
Msg func(Args... args)
{
    return func2( std::forward_as_tuple( args... ),
                  std::make_index_sequence< 2*sizeof...(Args) >() );
}
```

[**Live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/466459a8fedf483c)

Comment: Fail to compile with empty pack. Why not use `forward_as_tuple` instead of array of pointer ?

Answer (score 3):

Using C++14 features, a general solution can be obtained:

```
struct Msg {
    std::vector<int> values;
};

template <std::size_t... indices, typename Tuple, typename OutputIt>
void copy(std::index_sequence<indices...>, Tuple&& t, OutputIt out) {
    (void)std::initializer_list<int> {
        (*out++ = std::get<indices>(std::forward<Tuple>(t)), 0)...
    };
}

template <typename Tuple, typename OutputIt>
void copy(Tuple&& t, OutputIt out) {
    copy(std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<std::decay_t<Tuple>>{}>{},
         std::forward<Tuple>(t), out);
}

template <typename... Args>
Msg func(Args... args) {
    auto cat = std::tuple_cat(args...);
    Msg m{{sizeof...(args)}};
    copy(cat, std::back_inserter(m.values));
    return m;
}

// For demonstration:
template <typename... T>
auto foo(T&&... t) {return std::make_tuple(std::forward<T>(t)...);}
```

The usage is more flexible than before:

```
Msg msg = func(foo(1,2,3), foo(4), foo(5,6,7));
```

[**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7e8c24cbdbd0efc4).

You can define `foo` to be a (fixed sized) tuple as well, e.g. `using foo = std::tuple<int, int>;`, then your above example compiles without the auxiliary function (after adjusting the braces, of course).

Comment: I'd be slightly worried about the runtime-overhead is causes, but OPs question is not easy to solve in an overhead-free and elegant way - my answer is not really better, just different. +1